# Generating color templates for web pages

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm working in a program that called Artisteer 2. This program constructs template designs for joomla, dumpress, html, css, etc. How can I build an algorithm that generates the color of my site?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these sites:

http://www.colorspire.com/

http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Answer (score 0):

Also check out "Toucan" at http://aviary.com/ - it is an online color visualization tool.

Answer (score 0):

I keep all my favourites in here, http://delicious.com/neon1024/colour I won't paste them all, but there are some handy ones. I tend to like the ones where you can pick a palette.